# Boost::spirit sequence does not get parsed

Tags: boost, boost-spirit

I wrote this sample of code and expect it to print `OPERATION( OPERATOR(aaa) ID(bbb) )` but I get only `OPERATION ( OPERATOR(aaa) )` instead. Both `result2` and `it1 == it2` are true. Why do not operands get parsed?

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <boost/serialization/strong_typedef.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix1.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_core.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_operator.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_object.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/support.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/variant/recursive_variant.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace NsSemSDK
{

struct STreeConstructionRuleRegexp {
    std::string m_strEntity;
};

struct STreeConstructionRuleString {
    std::string m_strEntity;
};

struct STreeConstructionRuleIdentifier {
    std::string m_strEntity;
};

typedef int STreeConstructionRuleNumber;

typedef std::string STreeConstructionRuleOperation;
typedef boost::variant<STreeConstructionRuleRegexp, STreeConstructionRuleNumber, STreeConstructionRuleString, STreeConstructionRuleIdentifier> STreeConstructionRuleOperand;
typedef boost::tuple<STreeConstructionRuleOperation, std::vector<STreeConstructionRuleOperand> > STreeConstructionRuleOperationWithOperands;


std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const NsSemSDK::STreeConstructionRuleIdentifier& val);
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const NsSemSDK::STreeConstructionRuleString& val);
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const NsSemSDK::STreeConstructionRuleRegexp& val);
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const NsSemSDK::STreeConstructionRuleOperationWithOperands& val);


std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const NsSemSDK::STreeConstructionRuleOperationWithOperands& val)
{
    stream << "OPERATION( " << "OPERATOR(" << val.get<0>() << ")";
    for (int i = 0; i < val.get<1>().size(); i++)
    {
        stream << " " << val.get<1>()[i];
    }
    stream << " )";
    return stream;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const NsSemSDK::STreeConstructionRuleRegexp& val)
{
    return stream << "REGEXP(" << val.m_strEntity << ")";
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const NsSemSDK::STreeConstructionRuleString& val)
{
    return stream << "STR(" << val.m_strEntity << ")";
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const NsSemSDK::STreeConstructionRuleIdentifier& val)
{
    return stream << "ID(" << val.m_strEntity << ")";
}

}

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    NsSemSDK::STreeConstructionRuleRegexp,
    (std::string, m_strEntity)
)

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    NsSemSDK::STreeConstructionRuleString,
    (std::string, m_strEntity)
)

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    NsSemSDK::STreeConstructionRuleIdentifier,
    (std::string, m_strEntity)
)

namespace NsSemSDK{

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace phoenix = boost::phoenix;


template <typename Iterator, typename Skipper>
struct STreeContructionRulesGrammar : qi::grammar<Iterator, STreeConstructionRuleOperationWithOperands(), Skipper> // std::vector<STreeConstructionRule>()
{
    qi::rule<Iterator, STreeConstructionRuleOperationWithOperands(), Skipper> m_oOperationWithOperands;
    qi::rule<Iterator, STreeConstructionRuleOperation(), Skipper> m_oOperation;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::vector<STreeConstructionRuleOperand>(), Skipper> m_oOperandsList;
    qi::rule<Iterator, STreeConstructionRuleOperand(), Skipper> m_oOperand;
    qi::rule<Iterator, STreeConstructionRuleString(), Skipper> m_oString;
    qi::rule<Iterator, STreeConstructionRuleRegexp(), Skipper> m_oRegexp;
    qi::rule<Iterator, STreeConstructionRuleNumber(), Skipper> m_oNumber;
    qi::rule<Iterator, STreeConstructionRuleIdentifier(), Skipper> m_oIdentifier;

    STreeContructionRulesGrammar() : STreeContructionRulesGrammar::base_type(m_oOperationWithOperands)
    {
        m_oOperationWithOperands %= m_oOperation >  m_oOperandsList;
        m_oOperation %= qi::lexeme[+(qi::alnum)];
        m_oOperandsList %= qi::lit("[") >> (m_oOperand % ',') >> qi::lit("]");
        m_oOperand %= m_oString | m_oRegexp | m_oNumber | m_oIdentifier;

        m_oString %= qi::lit("\"") >> qi::lexeme[*(qi::char_ - '"')] >> qi::lit("\""); 
        m_oRegexp %= qi::lit("'") >> qi::lexeme[*(qi::char_ - '\'')] >> qi::lit("'"); 
        m_oNumber %= qi::int_;
        m_oIdentifier %= +(qi::alpha) >> qi::eps;
    }

};

}
using namespace NsSemSDK;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::string str("aaa [bbb]");
    STreeContructionRulesGrammar<std::string::iterator, boost::spirit::ascii::space_type> grammar;
    STreeConstructionRuleOperationWithOperands result;
    std::string::iterator it1 = str.begin(), it2 = str.end();
    bool result2 = qi::phrase_parse(it1, it2, grammar, boost::spirit::ascii::space, result);
    std::cout << result << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a perfect question, with a nice SSCCE. See my answer for more reasons why this is a legitimate question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used `BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG` like this

- http://liveworkspace.org/code/ecb721b4b30e1f117e8905c0f13218c2

As you can see, the parsing debug trace shows that `bbb` is being matched as an Identifier:

```
<m_oOperationWithOperands>
  <try>aaa [bbb]</try>
  <m_oOperation>
    <try>aaa [bbb]</try>
    <success> [bbb]</success>
    <attributes>[[a, a, a]]</attributes>
  </m_oOperation>
  <m_oOperandsList>
    <try> [bbb]</try>
    <m_oOperand>
      <try>bbb]</try>
      <m_oString>
        <try>bbb]</try>
        <fail/>
      </m_oString>
      <m_oRegexp>
        <try>bbb]</try>
        <fail/>
      </m_oRegexp>
      <m_oNumber>
        <try>bbb]</try>
        <fail/>
      </m_oNumber>
      <m_oIdentifier>
        <try>bbb]</try>
        <success>]</success>
        <attributes>[[[b, b, b]]]</attributes>
      </m_oIdentifier>
      <success>]</success>
      <attributes>[[[b, b, b]]]</attributes>
    </m_oOperand>
    <success></success>
    <attributes>[[[[b, b, b]]]]</attributes>
  </m_oOperandsList>
  <success></success>
  <attributes>[OPERATION( OPERATOR(aaa) )]</attributes>
</m_oOperationWithOperands>
```

So far, so good. So the question was why the result wasn't getting assigned into the tuple element in rule `m_oOperationWithOperands`. Here, I'm afraid I cannot tell you what you should have done.

I used my experience and checked whether the proper *fusion adaptations* were in effect for `tuple`s. On a whim I changed

```
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
```

to

```
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapted.hpp>
```

And now the output is:

```
OPERATION( OPERATOR(aaa) ID(bbb) )
```

See live at http://liveworkspace.org/code/c0da90349fbcae6655ab3e6a45f1ef69

> **P.S.**: I'd be tempted to say it is a bug in Qi that no diagnostic exists saying that the exposed attributes are being *incompletely* copied to the *attribute reference*. You may want to post this at https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/spirit-general